# ignoring a directory in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How do I stop eclipse from compiling and detecting errors in a bunch of .java files in a directory? I'm writing a type checker for a class and those files are test cases and I don't want them to be compiled or for the errors to show up in the problems tab.

Comment: http://robmayhew.com/eclipse-ignore-folder/ -- helpful?

Comment: I did this but the errors are still showing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse compiles only those classes in the source folders. Right click on the folder that contains these files, and click on `Build Path -> Exclude` to exclude that folder from being treated as a source folder and the compiler will ignore these files.